# Intercept variable name in a loop

Tags: c#

I'm creating a function for reading an integer number content in a custom object.

The custom object is contained to a wrapping class and is composed of:

```
public class IODBTLMNG
    {
        public int data0 = new int();
        public int data1 = new int();
        public int data2 = new int();
        public int data3 = new int();
        public int data4 = new int();
        public int data5 = new int();
        public int data6 = new int();
        public int data7 = new int();
        public int data8 = new int();
        public int data9 = new int();
        public int data10 = new int();  
    }
```

I have the need in the class of use of the object, to cycle the objects "Data" and I can not use an array because the original function belonging to the dll does not allow it (wrapping class with DllExtern).
The function I would like to implement should cycle the DataX fields.
I write an example below:

```
 private int[] GetInteger()
    {
        int[] result = new int[10];

        IODBTLMNG obj = new IODBTLMNG();
        obj = PopolateObject();

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            result[i] = obj.(data + i); // The problem is this (Data i)
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Is it possible?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the answers. For integer it work. I need to complicate the question. If data isn't an integer but a class and IODBTLMNG is composed from:

```
public class IODBTLMNG
{
    public IODBTLMNG_data data1 = new IODBTLMNG_data();
    public IODBTLMNG_data data2 = new IODBTLMNG_data();
    public IODBTLMNG_data data3 = new IODBTLMNG_data();
    public IODBTLMNG_data data4 = new IODBTLMNG_data();
    public IODBTLMNG_data data5 = new IODBTLMNG_data();
    public IODBTLMNG_data data6 = new IODBTLMNG_data();
    public IODBTLMNG_data data7 = new IODBTLMNG_data();
    public IODBTLMNG_data data8 = new IODBTLMNG_data();
    public IODBTLMNG_data data9 = new IODBTLMNG_data();
    public IODBTLMNG_data data10 = new IODBTLMNG_data();
}
```

And IODBTLMNG_data is composed from:

```
public class IODBTLMNG_data
{
    public int T_code;
    public int life_count;
}
```

If I need to extract T_code, can I use reflection? Thanks

**Solved Edit:**

Ok...I solved using a support variable IODBTLMNG_data (obj_data) in this mode:

```
obj_data = (IODBTLMNG_data)(obj.GetType().GetField($"data{i}").GetValue(obj));
```

and:

```
 result[i] = obj_data.T_code;
```

Thanks

Comment: It's possible using reflection. If you could change the `IODBTLMNG` class to contain an array of ints instead of different properties, then it would be possible without reflection.

Comment: I'd personally use another class that had an array. Work with that and then map to a new instance of `IODBTLMNG` when needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you *have to* work with `IODBTLMNG` class as it is and you *can't redesign* it, I suggest using *Reflection*:

```
 using System.Reflection;

 ...

 result[i] = (int) (obj.GetType().GetField($"data{i + 1}").GetValue(obj));
```

**Edit:** in other words (see comments), if you want to read a `public` (*instance*) field by its name:

```
 var obj = ...
 string fieldName = "T_code"; // or "life_count", or "data5" - whatever

 object value = obj     // for the instance obj
   .GetType(fieldName)  // get its type (IODBTLMNG_data)
   .GetField()          // given type, find (with a help of Reflect) field description
   .GetValue(obj);      // read field's value for the obj instance

 int myResult = (int) value; // cast to int
```

Comment: if data were a structure that contains:                                            public class IODBTLMNG_data
        {
            public int T_code;
            public int life_count;                                                                           }         if I need to extract T_code how should I do with reflection? Thank you

Comment: @Tarma: Sorry? I don't follow you. I you want read `obj`s field by its name (let it be `"theFieldName"`): `object result = obj.GetType().GetField(theFieldName).GetValue(objj);`

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in something that will give you an array/List-like accessor
You can even make it an `IEnumerable` so it can be used with LINQ etc

```
public class IODBTLMNGWrapper: IEnumerable<int>
{
    private readonly IODBTLMNG wrapped;

    public IODBTLMNGWrapper(IODBTLMNG wrapped)
    {
        this.wrapped = wrapped ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(wrapped));
    }

    public int Length { get; } = 11;

    public int this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            switch(index)
            {
                case 0: return wrapped.data0;
                case 1: return wrapped.data1;
                case 2: return wrapped.data2;
                case 3: return wrapped.data3;
                case 4: return wrapped.data4;
                case 5: return wrapped.data5;
                case 6: return wrapped.data6;
                case 7: return wrapped.data7;
                case 8: return wrapped.data8;
                case 9: return wrapped.data9;
                case 10: return wrapped.data10;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Bad index {index}");
            }
        }
        set
        {
            switch (index)
            {
                case 0: wrapped.data0 = value; break;
                case 1: wrapped.data1 = value; break;
                case 2: wrapped.data2 = value; break;
                case 3: wrapped.data3 = value; break;
                case 4: wrapped.data4 = value; break;
                case 5: wrapped.data5 = value; break;
                case 6: wrapped.data6 = value; break;
                case 7: wrapped.data7 = value; break;
                case 8: wrapped.data8 = value; break;
                case 9: wrapped.data9 = value; break;
                case 10:wrapped.data10 = value; break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Bad index {index}");
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            yield return this[i];
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Calling code becomes

```
private int[] SumItemsGreaterThan1000(IODBTLMNG data)
{
    var wrapper = IODBTLMNGWrapper(data);
    int sum = 0;
    foreach(var i in wrapper.Where(n => n > 1000)
        sum += i;
    return sum;
}
```